# Delphi XML validation with XSD

Tags: xml, delphi, xsd

I'm using Delphi 10.2 update 3.
I followed these instructions to validate a generated xml document.

[What effect does the attribute noNamespaceSchemaLocation have on XML parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594267/what-effect-does-the-attribute-nonamespaceschemalocation-have-on-xml-parsing)

[Validate XML using Windows DOM and TXMLDocument: doesn't work on some computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654095/validate-xml-using-windows-dom-and-txmldocument-doesnt-work-on-some-computers)

[schema validation with msxml in delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446635/schema-validation-with-msxml-in-delphi)

**But I have an error.**
"The attribute 'noNamespaceSchemaLocation' on the element 'jegyzek_adatok' is not defined in the DTD/Schema."

**Preparing the xml document:**

```
const
  cSchemaLocation = 'noNamespaceSchemaLocation';

procedure PreparePostBookXMLDocument(ARootNode: IXMLNode);
var
  xDoc: IXMLDocument;
begin
  if ARootNode.OwnerDocument = nil then Exit;

  xDoc := ARootNode.OwnerDocument;
  xDoc.Version := '1.0';
  xDoc.Encoding := 'windows-1250';
  xDoc.Options := xDoc.Options + [doNodeAutoIndent];
  ARootNode.Attributes['xmlns:xsi'] := 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance';
  ARootNode.Attributes['xsi:' + cSchemaLocation] := 'https://www.posta.hu/static/internet/download/level_ver8_ugyfeleknek_8p4.xsd';
end;
```

**The validation:**

```
function ValidatePostBookXMLDocument(ARootNode: IXMLNode): IResult;
var
  xDocument: IXMLDocument;
  xMsxmlDoc: IXMLDOMDocument3;
  xXSDDocument: IXMLDOMDocument3;
  xSchemaCache: IXMLDOMSchemaCollection;
  xSchemaLocation: string;
  xError: IXMLDOMParseError;
begin
  Result := ERRUnknown;
  try
    if ARootNode = nil then Exit;

    xDocument := ARootNode.OwnerDocument;
    if xDocument = nil then Exit;

    xMsxmlDoc := ((xDocument.DOMDocument as IXMLDOMNodeRef).GetXMLDOMNode as IXMLDOMDocument3);

    xSchemaLocation := ARootNode.AttributeNodes.FindNode(cSchemaLocation).Text;
    xXSDDocument := CoDOMDocument60.Create;
    xXSDDocument.async := False;
    xXSDDocument.validateOnParse := True;
    if not xXSDDocument.load(xSchemaLocation) then Exit(MakeErrorResult(ohFileError, 'A validációhoz szükséges séma fájlt nem sikerült betölteni!'));

    xSchemaCache := CoXMLSchemaCache60.Create;
    xSchemaCache.add('', xXSDDocument);
    xMsxmlDoc.schemas := xSchemaCache;
    xError := xMsxmlDoc.validate;
    case xError.errorCode of
      S_OK: Result := Success;
      else Exit(MakeErrorResult(ohError, xError.reason));
    end;
  except
    on E:Exception do Result := HandleException;
  end;
end;
```

The generated xml file, is valid via https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html#.

[**The XSD (https://www.posta.hu/static/internet/download/level_ver8_ugyfeleknek_8p4.xsd):**](https://www.posta.hu/static/internet/download/level_ver8_ugyfeleknek_8p4.xsd)

[**My generated xml (on my google drive):**](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1G0a8ox5VQ9_H6In7OmRMtFOI25QMN811)

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the specific XML parser you're using in Delphi. However, to answer the general questions:

- the attribute `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` declares where to find an XSD schema for the document (specifically, a schema for elements in no namespace)
- it has no effect unless you invoke XSD schema validation. Some parsers may interpret the presence of this attribute as a signal to invoke schema validation, but that's fairly unusual.
- when validating against an XSD schema, this attribute is always valid provided that its value is a valid URI. The schema doesn't need to explicitly permit this attribute.
- when validating against a DTD, this attribute is INVALID unless the DTD is written to explicitly allow it.

I suspect that you are running the parser with DTD validation enabled and that the DTD does not permit this attribute to be present. But that's a bit of a guess.

Comment: I didn't want to use the xsd as a local file.
It saw to be a good idea, to take an attribute into the xml.
I don't know, the MSXML's parser how works exactly (it may be the explorer's parser). The xml, what I have to make, doesn't use namespaces.
So I try to use the "noNamespaceSchemaLocation" attribute.

After I removed all the attributes about the schema location from the xml, and I used the xsd as a local file, the validation successfully finished.
It's a half solution for me (I have to read more much about the xml and DTD/schemas), but the problem has solved!
Thank you, Michael Kay!